# Virt-install error: can't load ignition file

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt, coreos

I'm trying to install Fedora CoreOS using virt-install, as described here: 
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/getting-started/

The exact command I'm running: `virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n fcos -r 2048 --os-variant=fedora31 --import --graphics=none --disk size=10,backing_store=fedora-coreos-31.20200310.3.0-qemu.x86_64.qcow2 --qemu-commandline="-fw_cfg name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=/home/test/Downloads/example.ign"`

is returning this error:

```
Allocating 'fcos.qcow2'                                                                                              |  10 GB  00:00:00     
ERROR    internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2020-04-05T14:52:47.919380Z qemu-system-x86_64: -fw_cfg name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=/home/test/Downloads/example.ign: can't load /home/test/Downloads/example.ign
Removing disk 'fcos.qcow2'                                                                                           |    0 B  00:00:00     
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
```

I'm running this command as root. The ignition file is working as I've successfully used it to deploy this VM from an iso file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, based on Getting Started tip, you may need to run chcon command.

> If running with SELinux enabled, you may need to change the label of the Ignition file to allow access: chcon -t svirt_home_t path/to/example.ign

Answer (score 3):

Most probably it is an AppArmor issue. Ran into the same issue, tried all the possible file permission workarounds like `setfacl -m u:libvirt-qemu:rx` and `chcon -t` but it ended up to be an AppArmor profile limitation:

To resolve the issue change `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/TEMPLATE.qemu` to include the path to ignition configs:

```
#
# This profile is for the domain whose UUID matches this file.
#

#include <tunables/global>

profile LIBVIRT_TEMPLATE flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/libvirt-qemu>
  /home/test/Downloads/example.ign rk,
  /etc/ignition/**.ign rk,
}
```

Note that I added `/etc/ignition/**.ign` glob as an example if you decide to organize all Ignition configs for your VMs in future.

This way you will be able to create a CoreOS VM using `virt-install`.

As an option you can disable AppArmor for Qemu by setting `security_driver = "none"` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` but this is strongly discouraged I would say.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you run `virt-install` as root, the VM as launched by libvirt's `qemu:///system` is likely using the `qemu` user. That `qemu` user probably doesn't have search+read access to /home/test for example. Moving the file to `/tmp` would fix it, or open up the permissions on the whole `/home/test` file path

Answer (score 2):

Using more recent versions of [virt-manager](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/commit/65f93e5d60c5076aeba8a3059db4832e4e0db5de) (6.5) and [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsSysinfo) (3.0), you can now use

```
virt-install \
    --sysinfo type=fwcfg,entry0.name=opt/com.coreos/config,entry0.file=${IGNITION_CONFIG} \
    ...
```

which will take care of properly setting the labels on the ignition file.